# catch reject from promise

Tags: javascript, promise, co

I want to hold the error from `func()` `reject`, not direct to `onError()` by choise,

Before I always let `func()` `resolve`, and determine return result after `yield func()`,
if I want to direct to `onError()` use `throw ..;`

Wondering any better idea I can just let `func()` `reject` but detemire after `yield func()` , direct to `onError()` or not

```
co(function* () {
  yield func();
  // if reject catch here, not direct to onError 


  yield func();
  // if reject don't catch here just direct to onError

}).then(function (response) {
  response = JSON.stringify(response);
  res.send(response);
}, function (err) {
  onError(err);
});


// ...
func: function() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
    ...
    reject();
  });
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`co` supports `try/catch`:

```
co(function* () {
  try{
      yield func();
  }
  catch {
     // if reject catch here, not direct to onError 
  }




  yield func();
  // if reject don't catch here just direct to onError

}).then(function (response) {
  response = JSON.stringify(response);
  res.send(response);
}, function (err) {
  onError(err);
});
```

See docs : https://www.npmjs.com/package/co#examples